# Change numpy array values by giving corner indices

Tags: python, numpy, image-manipulation, matrix-indexing

i am trying to change certain matrix values of a 2D numpy array.
I need this to classify areas of an image in pixel level.

Imagine having a matrix like:

```
a = [ [1,  2,  3,  4 ]
      [5,  6,  7,  8 ] 
      [9,  10, 11, 12]
      [13, 14, 15, 16] ].
```

I want to change values by "drawing" a line. Like i put a line through the values 5, 11 and 16.
I'd wish to change the values below this line to 0. So having:

```
a = [ [1,  2,  3,  4 ]
      [5,  6,  7,  8 ] 
      [0,  0, 11,  12]
      [0,  0,  0,  16] ].
```

Regularly with banded matrices and diagonal functions it is easy to change matrix values. But how to do with irregular geometric wishes?
Another use case is to have a geometric figure, or in detail the corner points of a geometric figure.
Is there a way to give four corner points to create a box?

E.g. `corner_points = [ [1,1], [3,1], [1,2], [4,3] ]` 
Which would lead to:

```
a = [ [0,  0,  3,  4 ]
      [0,  0,  0,  8 ] 
      [0,  0,  0,  12]
      [13, 14,  0, 16] ]
```

I don't need it to be perfectly accurate, a rough approximation is really helpful!

Thanks in advance and if i failed to explain it right, please ask questions so i can do this challenge.